# To check if session is available or not

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried some code in `Application_Error` like this

```
Session["mysession"] = "Some message";
```

but the problem is sometimes session is not available in `Application_Error`. So I want to check whether session is available or not.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Session` doesn't always exist within the context of the current `Application_Error`. Try the following:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Context.Handler is IRequiresSessionState || 
        Context.Handler is IReadOnlySessionState)
    {
         // Session exists
         Session["mysession"] = "Some message";
    }
}
```

Comment: This will give the exception "Session state is not available in this context." if session is not available.

Comment: Yes I did. Now I doubt this may have something to do with Application_Error

Comment: Yeah this will do for me. Thanks !