# Session availability check in an IIS7 module failes

Tags: c#-4.0, session, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, httpmodule

I have a custom IIS Module, registered on the context_PostAcquireRequestState event.
I want to cache the result in the session, if it's available.
But for some reason, I keep getting the "Session state is not available in this context. " error, when I try to check if the session is available.

```
if (application.Session != null)
```

That is my session check.
I tried the answer from this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769711/to-check-if-session-is-available-or-not). But got the same error.

P.S. 
I don't think that relying on an exception as a normal flow is a good practice.
So, I want to avoid just catching the error and proceeding without the session.